# Transaction commit failed as flushmode is MANUAL

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions, readonly, manual

I am facing a weird issue since migrating to Spring 4.
Application makes an Ajax call using dwr. Ajax helper calls the service.

Error is

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Write operations are not allowed in read-only mode (FlushMode.MANUAL): Turn your Session into FlushMode.COMMIT/AUTO or remove 'readOnly' marker from transaction definition.
```

AjaxSiteDnsHelper.java

```
public void removeSiteDnsEntry(Long siteDnsEntryId) throws ItemNotFoundException, ServiceException {
    final Site site = getSite();
    site.setModifiedBy(getUser());
    for (SiteDns siteDns : site.getSiteDnsEntries()) {
        if (siteDns.getId().equals(siteDnsEntryId)) {
            site.getSiteDnsEntries().remove(siteDns);
            break;
        }
    }
    siteServices.saveOrUpdateSite(site);
}


Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class SiteServices extends NavigationServices implements ISiteServices {


//some code
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void saveOrUpdateSite(final Site site) throws ServiceException {

    siteDAO.saveOrUpdate(site);

    if (site.getExternalFeedUser() == null) {
        site.setExternalFeedUser(createDefaultSiteUser(site));
    } else {
        site.getExternalFeedUser().setUsername("DOD " + URLMappingUtils.generateSiteUgcEditorUsername(site));
    }

    LOG.info("Setting default user to '" + site.getExternalFeedUser().getUsername() + "'");
    userDAO.saveOrUpdate(site.getExternalFeedUser());
}
```

web.xml has

hibernateOSIV
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter
    
        sessionFactoryBeanName
        sessionFactory

persistence-context.xml has

```
<bean id="hibernateInterceptor" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateInterceptor">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

transactional-context.xml has

```
  <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager" >
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
  </bean>

  <tx:annotation-driven/>
```

Someone suggested me that I need to refactor the code to remove hierarchies of classes as something going wrong while creating proxies. 
I put debug on OpenSessionInViewFilter.setFlushMode. But it doesn't seem to be called and default flushmode of MANUAL is being used.

Comment: I tried different things like remove readonly from top of the class, add init-param flushmode AUTO in web.xml for OpenSessionInViewFilter. flushmode AUTO only suppressed the error but didn't save the object. Also added @Transaction attribute on ajax helper but it didn't help.

Comment: **Can you please help.**